# flutter : can't set Border Radius for container and on Tap not work in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, containers, click, flutter-layout

I Have Problem about borderRadius of Container in flutter .
I can't set it for container

I want to create something like this image :

[image]

and other problem about onTap() .
ontap not work and i don't know why .

here this is part of my code:

```
InkWell(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: const Text("فلسفه",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF201F1E),
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                    color: greyColor,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    print("something");
                   
                  },
                ),
```

can any one help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with this

```
InkWell(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: const Text("فلسفه",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFF201F1E),
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center),

          ),
          onTap: () {
            print("something");

          },
        )
```

output:

[image]

Comment: onTap working on my emulator. what about the response you got?

Comment: when I've click on items ,I've get nothing

Answer (score 0):

delete this code in your inkWell

```
borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
```

and put this in inside your Container

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
),
```

this will fix your BorderRadius problem

test it i think this will fix that onTap problem as well

Comment: when I've put this in container T I've get error in emulator

Comment: @faezehajimohammadhoseini what was your error?

Comment: oh I get it if you define decoration and box decoration you should define color inside the box decoration